# Jmeter not performing second loop when a while loop is introduced

Tags: performance, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have a scenario as below,
Post a webpage which have a search bar, where i have to search for 5 different strings.

Hence i created thread group as below,
No of threads : 3
No of iterations : 2

Inside the script i included a while loop to search for 5 strings using a CSV config(added 5 string in a csv file).

CSV Config:
Recycle on EOF : False
Stop thread on EOF : True

Now the jmx is making only 1 iterations which makes actual output as below, 
Actual output:
URL Launch : 3 users x 1 iteration = 3 hits
Search hits : 3 users x 1 iteration x 5 strings = 15 hits

EXPECTED OUTPUT:
URL Launch : 3x2 = 6 hits
Search hits : 3x2x5 = 30 hits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to achieve this using CSV Data Set Config and While Controller, consider amending your test plan as follows:

1. Change While Controller to [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) and use the following [__groovy()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) function in the "Loop Count" section:

   ```
   ${__groovy(new File('test.csv').readLines().size()  ,)}
   ```
2. Instead of referencing the variable from CSV use [__StringFromFile()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) function like:

   ```
   ${__StringFromFile(test.csv,,,)}
   ```
3. Just replace `test.csv` with the full or relative path to your own CSV file and you should be good to go:

   [image]

More information on using JMeter Functions: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction/)